# The sentence meaning and type

Tags: passive-voice

I was recently reading a text on YouTube channel. The sentence written was

> It was a great pleasure to apoear on Roqe media this week and be interviwed by Mr.James, talking about our YouTube channel.

How this sentence starts with a past form and contunue with a passive form after a conjenction. Please advise what is the meaning of "Be interviewed by" can we use only "interviewed" instead of "be interviewed"?

Answer (score 1):

1

> It was a great pleasure to [appear] on Roqe media this week and be [interviewed] by Mr.James, talking about our YouTube channel.

(1) is fine. It has used parallelism to omit the second 'to' in (2) below, which is a full version of the example.

2
It was a great pleasure **to appear** on Roqe media this week and **to be interviewed** by Mr.James, talking about our YouTube channel.

3

> It was a great pleasure **to appear** on Roqe media this week and **interviewed** by Mr.James, talking about our YouTube channel.

(3) is not grammatical, as 'interviewed' is in past tense and hence not parallel with 'to appear', which is in the infinitive form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding me.